# NoClassDefFoundError when invoking EJB from Tomcat - class is POJO on the classpath

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, noclassdeffounderror

I have the following arrangement :

```
 Tomcat   --EJB-invokation-->  JBoss
(6.0.14)                      (5.1.0)
```

The two servers are running on the same machine.

When I run the Tomcat webapp, I get the following error in the Tomcat logs:

```
2011-11-02 15:59:02,077 [http-9320-4] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/frontend].[action]- "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet action a généré une exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/app/transfer/internal/dto/account/AccountWithDemandDTO
        at com.mycompany.app.back.services.ServiceImpl.findAccount(ServiceImpl.java:925)
        at com.mycompany.app.back.services.ServiceImpl.findAccount(ServiceImpl.java:879)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2703.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

The class that is not being found makes up part of an ear on JBoss :

```
applicationear.ear
    - META-INF
        - application.xml
        - ...
    - transfer-internal-dto-6.0.9.jar
    - ...
```

`application.xml` is made up of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<application ...>
    <display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <module><ejb>backend-services-6.0.9.jar</ejb></module>
    <module><java>transfer-internal-dto-6.0.9.jar</java></module>
    ...
</application>
```

Looking at the JMX console, I can see that this Jar file is deployed, along with the other jars that make up the ear:

```
id="vfszip:/misc/JavaEE/package/myapp/back/6.0.9/deploy/applicationear.ear/transfer-internal-dto-6.0.9.jar/",type=SubDeployment
```

So for me the class is present on JBoss. On the Tomcat side, the client application is deployed as a war:

```
frontend.war
     - WEB-INF
         - lib
             - transfer-internal-dto-6.0.9.jar
             - ...
     - META-INF
         - MANIFEST.MF
```

The `Class-Path` declaration in the manifest includes `lib/transfer-internal-dto-6.0.9.jar`.

I'm a bit stuck as to what the problem might be - does anyone have any ideas?

A few useful bits of information:

- Java 1.6.0_18
- everything is packaged using Maven
- applications are deployed on JBoss using twiddle - hot deploy is disabled
- this happened after a graceful restart of the machine - the same application was working before the restart - the application has not been modified between the restarts
- the DTO object is a POJO that implements Serializable - two fields of the class are other POJOs (both implementing Serializable, both in the same jar). One of these secondary POJOs references two enums which are in a different .jar. This secondary .jar is correctly defined in application.xml and the MANIFEST.MF file. None of the POJOs in this tree has a static initializer nor similar instantiation-time code.
- this arrangement works fine on our test environment
- there is nothing in the JBoss logs
- the client side is a Struts app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took at difference of the JMX consoles in our test and production environments and noticed some differences. This is particularly strange as the environments are mastered (ie they are created from scripts) and the applications are also deployed from scripts, and everything worked before the planned shutdown. Therefore the only thing that seemed possible was some kind of problem during the deployment.

We therefore restarted the JBoss server, and everything functioned correctly.